# OnLocationChanged never called when gps is provider

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing a simple GPS app but I'm having some trouble with de 'gps' provider.

The problem is that when I request updates from the 'gps' provider, onLocationChanged is never called. I have granted all the permissions needed and I have tested that the 'gps' provider is enabled. I have tested it on 2 different phones and it didn't work in neither of them (so the problem can't be the gps of my smartphone).

Moreover, if I change the provider and I use the 'network' one, it does work with the same code, that is to say, onLocationChanged is called periodically.

Here's my code:

```
public class Capturador extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, SensorEventListener, LocationListener {

boolean lockLocalizacion = false;

private static final long TIEMPO_MIN = 0;//10 * 1000; // 10 segundos
private static final long DISTANCIA_MIN = 0;//5; // 5 metros
private LocationManager manejador;
private String gpsLatActual;
private String gpsLongActual;
private String gpsAltActual;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.primeracapa);

    manejador = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location localizacion = getLastKnownLocation();

    txtGPS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.localizacionEdit);
    if (localizacion == null) {
        txtGPS.setText(R.string.loc_unknown);
        gpsLatActual = "";
        gpsLongActual = "";
        gpsAltActual = "";
    } else {
        txtGPS.setText("(" + Double.toString(localizacion.getLongitude()) + ", " + Double.toString(localizacion.getLatitude()) + ", "
                + Double.toString(localizacion.getAltitude()) + ")");
        gpsLatActual = Double.toString(localizacion.getLatitude());
        gpsLongActual = Double.toString(localizacion.getLongitude());
        gpsAltActual = Double.toString(localizacion.getAltitude());
        lockLocalizacion = true;
    }
}

private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        manejador = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = manejador.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = manejador.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
    else return null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        String best = manejador.getBestProvider(crit, true); //best is always gps (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        manejador.requestLocationUpdates(best, 0, 1, this); //writting LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER insted of 'best' does work
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        manejador.removeUpdates(this);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null) {
        txtGPS.setText(R.string.loc_desconocida);
        lockLocalizacion = false;
    } else {
        txtGPS.setText("(" + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + ", " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + ", "
                + Double.toString(location.getAltitude()) + ")");
        gpsLatActual = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        gpsLongActual = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        gpsAltActual = Double.toString(location.getAltitude());
        lockLocalizacion = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String proveedor) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String proveedor) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String proveedor, int estado, Bundle extras) {


 }
}
```

And the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="Capturador"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="Visualizador"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Ajustador" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity android:name="Visualizador2" android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
</application>
```

Comment: can you show us the rest of your manifest?

Comment: Are you testing indoors? GPS is likely to have problems in that case.

Comment: There's the manifest. And yes, I'm testing indoors, I'll try to test it outdoors, that may be the issue. Anyway, I launched Google Maps, and it knew my location, but my app didn't. Does Google Maps use only gps provider or it depends on the available ones?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen you were right, outdoors it updates perfectly. Write the comment as an answer so I can check it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

GPS depends on signals from geostationary satellites and typically has serious problems or doesn't work at all indoors.

One solution of course is testing outdoors. This may not always be the most convenient option. One may also write test code simulating GPS completely from scratch, but Android does allow the implementation of fake location providers. The benefit is that code using the real providers and fake providers can be exactly the same.

There's for example [this article by PhoneArena](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Heres-how-to-easily-fake-your-GPS-location-on-Android_id62775) explaining how to use a fake location provider. The steps are:

- Change the device's location settings to use GPS only
- Get a fake location provider from Play Store or write your own
- The Developer mode needs to be enabled on the device
- Enable "Allow mock locations" in Developer options
- Select the mock location provider from the dialog (applicable in Android 6 and beyond)
- Use whatever fake location provider you used to simulate the location or a series of location updates.

This is a very brief and basic answer added to avoid answering a question in the comments only and there's probably a lot more to read about GPS problems and location spoofing elsewhere on Stack Overflow.